# LDAP searching AD finds no entries

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

My company has Active Directory set up. I am making an application whose login system should be linked to that AD, so I set up Spring LDAP authentication to implement it.

But when I try to log in to the application, I get

```
Failed to locate directory entry for authenticated user: my.name

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'DC=dev,DC=company,DC=corp'
```

My Spring Security code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("company.hr", "ldap://10.23.1.1:389/dc=dev,dc=company,dc=corp");
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        return provider;
    }
}
```

One of the problems is that our AD structure is really branched out, and each of those organizational units has further subdivision:

[image: AD tree structure]

Reading up on LDAP, I thought giving it only the path to the common parent folder should do recursive search through the tree and find the matching user, no matter what OU they are in, and indeed, if I do a `dsquery` from command prompt it does return the queried users, no matter where they are. However, that doesn't happen in Spring. I've read just about everything there is to find on the topic, and debugged for hours - but it seems my parameters are set correctly, yet I still get thrown the Exception.

My question would be - how to make Spring see that the user is, in fact, in Active Directory, without specifying the complete URL to that specific user (since there are dozens of different OUs)?

Comment: Perform the search within JXplorer to get the parameter right. You do not indicate the parameters and values for the search you are using. Appears you are looking for my.name. Try dsquery user -samid my.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Sometimes, rereading the documentation for Xth time actually helps.

I changed the constructor call of the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider from this

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("company.hr", "ldap://10.23.1.1:389/dc=dev,dc=company,dc=corp");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

    return provider;
}
```

to this

```
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("company.hr", "ldap://10.23.1.1:389", "dc=dev,dc=company,dc=corp");
```

The third parameter in the constrcutor is in fact "rootDn", so that's the place where it should be passed, not as an extension of the URL.